# First and last item of listview are acting the same

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, baseadapter

I am using a ListView to show a list of users. To delete user I can select users with a checkbox availaible on each row of the listview to select or unselect users.
Unfortunatly when I check the first checkbox, the last checkbox is acting the same and is checked aswell. Same when I select the last one, the first one is selected aswell.

I have this code in my adapter.

I don't see how both items in listview can be linked like that but hope some of you have some ideas.

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.modele_liste_patient, parent, false);
            viewHolder.champNomPrenom = convertView.findViewById(R.id.modele_liste_patient_nom_prenom_patient);
            viewHolder.champDate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.modele_liste_patient_date_naissance_patient);
            viewHolder.icon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.modele_liste_patient_image_patient);
            viewHolder.checkBox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.bonjour);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag() ;
        }

        viewHolder.champNomPrenom.setText(nom_prenom.get(position));
        viewHolder.champDate.setText(date_naissance.get(position));
        viewHolder.checkBox.setId(id_patient.get(position));

        if (supression) {

        ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.aurevoir);

        viewHolder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = ((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).checkBox;
                System.out.println(cb);
                if (cb.isChecked()) {

                    System.out.println("CLICKED ON ID : " + cb.getId());
                    Cabinet.supprimerIdPourSupression(cb.getId());
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                }
                else {

                    System.out.println("CLICKED ON ID : " + cb.getId());
                    Cabinet.ajouterIdPourSupression(cb.getId());
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }

        File imgFile = new File(image.get(position));

        if (imgFile.exists()) {

            Picasso.get()
                    .load(imgFile)
                    .resize(80, 80)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .transform(new CircleTransform())
                    .into(viewHolder.icon);
        } else {

            Picasso.get()
                    .load("url")
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_action_utilisateur_default)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_action_utilisateur_default)
                    .transform(new CircleTransform())
                    .into(viewHolder.icon);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {

        TextView champNomPrenom;
        TextView champDate;
        ImageView icon;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }
}
```